# How can I change the prompt displayed by Sphinx when documenting interactive sessions?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I am currently using [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) to document a mixed-language project, such that the documentation includes examples of interactive sessions not just in Python, but also in bash and the Windows command-line, as well as MATLAB and other interpreters. While Pygments takes care of highlighting everything nicely, all of the interactive sessions I've included in the documentation so far show up in HTML output preceded by the Python prompt, `>>>`. How can I change that prompt to `$`, for example, when documenting bash sessions?

---

**Edited to clarify:**

As documented in the Sphinx manual, under "[Showing code examples](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/code.html#showing-code-examples)," ReST source for a Sphinx document can contain code like:

```
>>> # python code here
>>> print "foo"
foo
```

This code then gets turned into markup like that demonstrated in [the documentation of argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#creating-a-parser) in the Python standard library documentation, showing the code after the `>>>` as a highlighted snippet. Though it is clear that one can simply typeset unhighlighted blocks with other prompt characters, I am wondering how to combine a prompt other than `>>>` with the interactive prompt styling shown in [the argparse example](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#creating-a-parser).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Sphinx does not add prompts to the HTML output; prompts are supposed to be in the documentation source. Can you show us the reST source for a sample interactive bash session?

Comment: If I add something to the ReST source that looks like a traditional text representation of a bash session, starting each line with `$`, then Sphinx will not typeset that in code style. On the other hand, if I start a ReST source line with `>>>`, then it will do so, obeying the most recent `.. highlight::` directive. That said, the HTML output still contains the `>>>`, with no apparent way of changing what the prompt is typeset as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use, say, `$` as the prompt for bash snippets, but it cannot be used for Python if you want the output to be nicely highlighted.

`>>>` is recognized as the interactive Python prompt. But using another prompt won't work. [The documentation](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/code.html) says: "Normal Python code is only highlighted if it is parseable", and something like

```
$ import sys
```

or

```
>> import sys
```

is not parseable as Python.

It is possible to use extensions to make Sphinx accept other Python prompts. The [ipython directive](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.sphinxext.ipython_directive.html) is an example (not tested by me).

---

These examples work well for me:

```
.. code-block:: bash

   $ pwd
   /home
   $ echo TEST
   TEST

.. code-block:: python

   >>> import sys
   >>> print "X"
   X
```

And the following produces identical formatting and highlighting:

```
.. highlight:: bash

::

   $ pwd
   /home
   $ echo TEST
   TEST

.. highlight:: python

::

   >>> import sys
   >>> print "X"
   X
```

For Python interactive sessions, no extra markup is actually needed (unless the most recent `.. highlight::` directive has a target other than `python`). Sphinx recognizes `>>>` automatically:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print "X"
X
```

Without any prompts, the code must be in a code-block (or literal block) to be formatted properly:

```
.. code-block:: python

   import sys
   print "X"
```